# Visual Studio 2012 - Don't search in certain file types

Tags: visual-studio-2012

When I do Cntl-Shift-F, there is a dropdown to specify filetype (*.cs for example). Is there any way to exclude certain file types from search? For example, if I wanted to search in all files without *.css extension.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596337/how-to-exclude-designer-cs-from-visual-studio-file-search) might help?  Though, looks like the UltraFind plugin is no more.

Comment: This is not exactly what you're looking for, but you can *include* multiple file types (*.cs, *.aspx, *.js) and not include ones you want to exclude