# Any way to apply an exclude list to the Visual Studio "Navigate To"-list?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I'd like to exclude code-generated files from the `Edit > Navigate To`-list which appears when hitting `Ctrl+,` in Visual Studio 2013, as these files are never to be modified by me manually and in those rare cases where I want to see the contents of them, I'll use the solution browser. Is there any way to do this? They produce a lot of noise in my search and greatly reduces the value of the `Navigate to`-function.

**Edit Nov 2016:** added an image for illustration in VS 2015. Very much an issue still. The first search hit is a `.g.cs` file in the `obj`-folder:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example of your search and what you prefer not to be displayed?

Comment: There are these VS Feedback items; sign in and upvote them if you like: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/All-in-one-Code-search-improperly-gives/10288101 and https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/For-XAML-components-Go-to-all-always-/1470388

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by "code-generated files" you are referring to files such as `.designer` that are also part of the solution (and found in solution explorer). After quite a bit of research into `Navigate To` I was unable to find any reference to such a configuration option.  Currently there appears to be only 3 options for configuration (discussed in the MSDN blog below).  A possible work around would be to leverage the built in filtering features of `Navigate To` (`@`, `Capitalization` and `Whitespace`) that are new to VS2013 as outlined in this MSDN blog:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mvpawardprogram/archive/2013/10/22/visual-studio-2013-navigate-to-improvements.aspx

Another article I found in my research: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/21/searching-and-navigating-code-in-vs-2010-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

**UPDATE:** I use the ReSharper plugin and only after posting this answer realized there is a `Filter results from generated files` feature to exclude generated files and is discussed at the link below.  Though it does not pertain to Navigate To, it may provide a satisfactory alternative:

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Options__Environment__Search_and_Navigation.html

**UPDATE (12/1/2015):** Now that some time has passed I decided to do a little more research and found a similar request posted on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596337/how-to-exclude-designer-cs-from-visual-studio-file-search). I found this to work pretty well, and VS will even save the list for you.

Comment: I was going to mention Resharper as well, as I found out about that feature today. That said, I can't get it to work. But that's a different issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21933466/i-cant-get-the-filter-results-from-generated-files-to-work-in-resharper-8 . I'm accepting your answer as this seems the state of the functionality today.

Comment: Just a note on the resharper solution: It is highly limited: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21933466/i-cant-get-the-filter-results-from-generated-files-to-work-in-resharper-8 Basically it does not solve my original problem

Comment: I just edited my question to include a screenshot from VS 2015. I'm really baffled Microsoft doesn't priortiize fixing this. BTW the SO-post you link to in the update from Dec 2015 is about the Quick Find-operation, not NavigateTo